# Create all possible factorisations from a prime factor list in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, factorization, decomposition

While I have seen posts about finding prime factors and divisors, I haven't found an answer to my question about factorisations in Python. I have a list of prime factors, i.e. for `24` it is `[2,2,2,3]`. I want from this list all possible factorisations, i.e. for `24` the output should be `[[2,12], [3,8], [4,6], [2,2,6], [2,3,4], [2,2,2,3]]`. 
I tried itertool approaches, but this created lots of duplicate answers and forgot others (like finding `[2,3,4]` but ignoring `[4,6]`).

I am specifically interested in an approach using the generated prime factor list. I have found a workaround with a recursive function.

```
def factors(n, n_list):                 
    for i in range(2, 1 + int(n ** .5)):
        if n % i == 0:
            n_list.append([i, n // i])
            if n // i not in primes:  #primes is a list containing prime numbers
                for items in factors(n // i, []):
                    n_list.append(sorted([i] + items))
    fac_list = [[n]]                  #[n] has to be added manually
    for facs in n_list:               #removes double entries     
        if facs not in fac_list:
            fac_list.append(facs)
    return fac_list
```

But this is time consuming for large n, since it has to look through all numbers, not just prime numbers. A combinatorics approach for a prime factor list should be much faster.

**Edit**: After looking through several resources, the best explanation of a good strategy is the highest rated answer [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893292/generate-all-partitions-of-a-set). Concise and easy to implement in any language, one prefers. Case closed.

Comment: Thanks for formatting my first post, jmd_dk. I took notice of the changes and will try to remember these rules. Is there a "blockshift to the right/left" command for code for proper indentation or do you have to add manually 4 spaces to each line?

Comment: Beginner's mistake - just use the `{}` button to format your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your task is to determine the [multiplicative partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_partition) of a number. Google should point you where you need to go. Stack Overflow already has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558292/how-to-find-multiplicative-partitions-of-any-integer).

Comment: Much appreciated. "Multiplicative partition". No wonder, I didn't find the answer without the right keyword.